getting error on starting the react-native app
ok so i started to learn react-native , i am trying to install it on my system from past 2 days , everything went well when it comes to installing , but when i try to start the app for the first time , it started to throw the error , I have already install the 17 version of openjdk, set up the path in ENV , install the android studio,
the error is
The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-11.0.22.7-hotspot\bin\java.exe
 user variable path
system variable path
and i have already try to manually install the eclipse adoptium , but it didn't work
please help

what is that screenshot supposed to show?  the only thing that would matter would be the path variable, of which you are only showing a very small portion.

@Claies please check noe
